# How to make a button to stop an excuted action

Tags: java

I made a button for starting an action which is listening to the server voice, So how can I make a button to stop listening to the server using a button"Stop Listening"?

```
private void CallActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       voiceReceiver tx1 = new voiceReceiver();
       tx1.captureAudio();

       System.out.println("voiceReceiver is calling >>>>");

       serVoice.setEnabled(false);
       Call.setEnabled(false);
       jButton3.setEnabled(true);
 }
```

Comment: So there's a bit going on there. Any more code to show?

Comment: What part of "how can I make a button" are you stuck on?  This question is way too vague as it stands.

Comment: if there is any help please this is the code uploaded here 

http://www.mediafire.com/?ec1dend3oepky5z

Comment: when I made the button start listening I called the uploaded class to the button "Start Listening", Now I want to make a stop button for stop listening to the voice after being executed.

Answer (score 2):

Store the voice receiver in a field, and stop it when the "Stop listening" button is clicked:

```
private void callActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    this.voiceReceiver = new VoiceReceiver();
    this.voiceReceiver.captureAudio();

    System.out.println("voiceReceiver is calling >>>>");

    serVoice.setEnabled(false);
    call.setEnabled(false);
    jButton3.setEnabled(true);
}   

private void stopListeningActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.voiceReceiver.stopCapturingAudio();
    ...
}
```

Note that I fixed your namings. In Java, by convention, methods start with a lowercase letter, and classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: +1 was about to add a comment about the capitalization

Comment: Well,  I don't know exactly what is inside stopCapturingAudio() method that you referred to.


I have uploaded the voiceListening coding file to this link

http://www.mediafire.com/?ec1dend3oepky5z

Comment: It was just an example. I don't know which classes you're using. But I guessed that if it has a method to start capturing, it also has one to stop capturing.